# Sql Query running in oracle SQL Developer But when i run the query from my JAVA program it is giving Sql exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am fetching some data using the following query

```
SELECT    
t.value_date,t.settlement_date,    
  (CASE WHEN NVL( t.settlement_date, '01-01-9999')='01-01-9999'
    THEN t.value_date
    ELSE t.settlement_date
  END) AS modified_value_date,    
  t.instrument_pk,    
  bct.base_ccy_pk,    
  i.contract_size,    
  lc.min_trading_unit AS min_trading_unit_lc,    
  bc.min_trading_unit AS min_trading_unit_bc    

FROM transaction t,    
  bc_transaction bct,    
  instrument i,    
  instrument lc,    
  instrument bc

WHERE t.status         = 'NORMAL'    
AND t.fund_pk          = 99436    
AND t.instrument_pk    = 235342    
AND t.instrument_pk    = i.instrument_pk    
AND t.local_ccy_pk     = lc.instrument_pk    
AND bct.transaction_pk = t.transaction_pk    
AND bct.base_ccy_pk    = bc.instrument_pk    
AND t.value_date      >= to_date('20121123000000','yyyymmddhh24miss')    
AND t.transaction_type = 'SECURITY_TRADE'    
ORDER BY modified_value_date,    
  t.processing_order,    
  t.txn_reference_no;
```

Problem is when i m running the above query in Oracle SQL Developer it's giving the proper result. But when i am trying to run the query from my java program using PreparedStatement it is producing an exception like **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month**

My problem got solved when i replace the date in CASE bolck with

```
(CASE WHEN NVL(t.settlement_date,to_date('99990101000000','yyyymmddhh24miss'))=to_date('99990101000000','yyyymmddhh24miss') 
    THEN t.value_date 
    ELSE t.settlement_date 
  END) AS modified_value_date
```

Now My questions is

1. **why there is such kind of discrepancy**?If the problem is with the to_date() then it should have given the same exception in SQL
   developer also.
2. **The problem does not end here** I saw when I m debugging my program from eclipse  again the same query is running perfectly
   without to_date() in NVL block the I checked and found that my JDK
   is 1.5 but the JRE was 1.6.Then I changed my JRE to 1.5 and debug
   the same java program and found that it is producing the same
   exception ,for the same query without to_date() in NVL block, at the
   time of debugging.

   Now I m completely messed up **why such kind of discrepancy between
   JRE 5 and JRE 6**?

**CAN ANYONE HELP ME?**

Comment: can you post your java code?

Comment: This whole `CASE WHEN NVL(...` doesn't make sense, why not just `NVL( t.settlement_date, t.value_date)` ? or `CASE WHEN  t.settlement_date is null then ...`

Comment: A.B.Cade You are right.There is no need to use CASE WHEN NVL(.... but my concern is something else.If i use my above sql it is running well in SQL DEVELOPER.but from my code it is producing exception java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month.if my sql is not right it should have given the same exception in sql developer also....

Comment: @AngshumanDey, for that you already got an aswer - when you use NVL with a date and a string oracle implicitly converts your string to a date according to `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` which can be different in different sessions opened by different tools, always use the `to_date` function to explicitly convert your string-dates. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14847616/1083652

Answer (score 2):

It is not about JRE version but about your session settings. You have specified string and left Oracle session to implicitely convert to date using NLS setting (likely NLS_DATE_FORMAT). 
 Do yourself a favor - never leave hardcoded value to depend on external setting. 
You can use `DATE'9999-01-01'` instead.